# Error. An item with the same key has already been added

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I got some code for handling Http errors in my Web application:

```
protected void Application_EndRequest()
{
    int code = Context.Response.StatusCode;

    switch (code)
    {
        case 404:
            {
                ExecuteErrorRequest();
                break;
            }
        case 403:
            {
                ExecuteErrorRequest();
                break;
            }
    }
}

private void ExecuteErrorRequest()
{            
    Response.Clear();
    var rd = new RouteData();
    rd.Values["controller"] = "Error";
    rd.Values["action"] = "Index";
    rd.Values["errorCode"] = Response.StatusCode;
    rd.Values["errorMsg"] = Response.StatusDescription;
    IController c = new ErrorController();
    c.Execute(new RequestContext(new HttpContextWrapper(Context), rd));
}
```

And Error controller:

```
public ActionResult Index(int errorCode, string errorMsg)
{
    ViewBag.Url = Request.Url.PathAndQuery;
    ViewBag.Code = errorCode;
    ViewBag.Msg = errorMsg;

    return View();
}
```

This code:

```
((IController)c).Execute(new RequestContext(new HttpContextWrapper(Context), rd));
```

sometimes throws me exception:

> An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in
>   System.Web.Mvc.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: An item with the same key has already been
>   added.

If in Index action of ErrorController delete parameters

```
public ActionResult Index()
```

and fill RouteData like this:

```
var rd = new RouteData();
rd.Values["controller"] = "Error";
rd.Values["action"] = "Index";
```

exception doesn't appear. I haven't any ideas why this exception appears...

*

UPD. StackTrace:

> at
>
> > System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentException(ExceptionResource resource) 
> >     at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key, TValue
> >     value, Boolean add)    at
> >     System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Add(TKey key, TValue value)
> >     at
> >     System.Web.Mvc.JsonValueProviderFactory.EntryLimitedDictionary.Add(String
> >     key, Object value)    at
> >     System.Web.Mvc.JsonValueProviderFactory.AddToBackingStore(EntryLimitedDictionary
> >     backingStore, String prefix, Object value)    at
> >     System.Web.Mvc.JsonValueProviderFactory.AddToBackingStore(EntryLimitedDictionary
> >     backingStore, String prefix, Object value)    at
> >     System.Web.Mvc.JsonValueProviderFactory.AddToBackingStore(EntryLimitedDictionary
> >     backingStore, String prefix, Object value)    at
> >     System.Web.Mvc.JsonValueProviderFactory.AddToBackingStore(EntryLimitedDictionary
> >     backingStore, String prefix, Object value)    at
> >     System.Web.Mvc.JsonValueProviderFactory.GetValueProvider(ControllerContext
> >     controllerContext)    at
> >     System.Web.Mvc.ValueProviderFactoryCollection.GetValueProvider(ControllerContext
> >     controllerContext)    at
> >     System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.get_ValueProvider()    at
> >     System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.GetParameterValue(ControllerContext
> >     controllerContext, ParameterDescriptor parameterDescriptor)    at
> >     System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.GetParameterValues(ControllerContext
> >     controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor)    at
> >     System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext
> >     controllerContext, String actionName)    at
> >     System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore()    at
> >     System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext requestContext)
> >     at
> >     System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.System.Web.Mvc.IController.Execute(RequestContext
> >     requestContext)    at
> >     ConstractionInvestments.Web.WebApiApplication.ExecuteErrorRequest() in
> >     c:\Develop\Projects\Mosaip\ConstractionInvestments\ConstractionInvestments.Web\Global.asax.cs:line
> >     52    at
> >     ConstractionInvestments.Web.WebApiApplication.Application_EndRequest()
> >     in
> >     c:\Develop\Projects\Mosaip\ConstractionInvestments\ConstractionInvestments.Web\Global.asax.cs:line
> >     36
>
> *

Comment: did you ever resolve this? are you using elmah by any chance?